# Is there any way in VSCode to jump to the Angular component that defines a tag, by clicking on the tag?

Tags: angular, ide, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm coding an Angular application using VSCode and sometimes I want to learn more about a tag that I come across.

For example, let's say I encounter a tag `<display-active-users>` and I want to determine some details about how it was implemented. Currently, to find the component file for this I do I a file search (`Ctrl + P`) and hopefull find a file named `display...`. If not, I do a full text search for `display-active-users`.

However, it would be much more ideal if I could just right click, or press some shortcut key on my keyboard, on `<display-active-users>` and be taken to the component file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could install the plug in "Angular Language Service", after that just need to Ctrl+Click the tag to go to the component definition.

Comment: That's awesome.  Sounds like exactly what I am looking for

Comment: An alternative could be the extension "Angular Follow Selector".
It doesn't feel as heavy as the language service for me.

Comment: ctrl + tab ... ctrl + shift + tab

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should install this plugin-

> Angular Essentials

```
ext install angular-essentials
```

This extension pack for Visual Studio Code adds extensions that are amazingly useful for Angular development.

Comment: Instead, use "Angular Follow Selector"

Comment: I did but it didn't work. I clicked it with command + click and nothing happed

Comment: Not working with angular 2

Answer (score 14):

You can install the following extension:

[Angular Component Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onixie.angular-component-extension)

> So you don't need to install a set of extensions.

Comment: Definitely works

Comment: October, 2023, using Angular 15, and this is the only solution that worked, now.  Angular Language Service didn't do the trick.